# MySQL: How to SELECT most recent row with same id

Tags: mysql, powershell

Let me preface this by saying that I'm very new to MySQL--any and all help is much appreciated.

I'm using SnipeIT (open source inventory management software) and I'm attempting to write a Powershell script to email users when their items are about to be overdue.

I'm trying to write the proper query to gather the contents I'll need for the email. There are 3 tables in question--Assets, Users, and Action_logs. I have a working query that joins Assets and Users to get all the pertinent information about an Asset and the User who has it checked out.

My issue is with my second query, in which I'm trying to get the staff member who checked out the item to a User. By Joining the Assets, Users, and Action_Log tables, using the Action_log table I can find all the actions of type 'checkout' for a given item. By looking at the most recent checkout, I can get the staff member's name and email address to add as a contact in the email.

My query is working as expected now, but I realize this will cause a problem in the long run. I'm working with the results and eventually sending the email via Powershell. I can take the results of the "checkout" query and dedupe them in Powershell, but I realize that this will take longer and longer as time goes on.

I'm looking to change my query so that for each 'asset_tag', only the most recent row (based on 'updated_at') is returned. That way, my script doesn't start getting slower over time.

Again, I'm very new to MySQL--I really appreciate your time and patience. My current query:

```
select
    assets.asset_tag, assets.assigned_type, assets.expected_checkin, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email, action_logs.action_type, action_logs.updated_at
from
    ((assets
inner join action_logs on assets.id = action_logs.item_id)
inner join users on action_logs.user_id = users.id)


where assets.assigned_type like 'App\\\\Models\\\\User'

and action_logs.action_type = 'checkout'

and assets.expected_checkin is not null

and assets.expected_checkin < '2019-11-31 12:12:12'   ;
```

To be specific with examples, what I'm getting back now is this:

[First Result, with all checkout actions included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNl3v.png)

And what I'd like to get back is something like this:

[Result, with only the most recent action for each asse_tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSTqs.png)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to recover the latest `updated_at` for each `(item_id, action_type)` tuple and inject it as a join condition:

```
select
    a.asset_tag, 
    a.assigned_type, 
    a.expected_checkin, 
    u.first_name, 
    u.last_name, 
    u.email, 
    l.action_type, 
    l.updated_at
from
    assets a
    inner join action_logs l 
        on  a.id = l.item_id 
        and l.action_type = 'checkout'
        and l.updated_at = (
            select max(l1.updated_at)
            from action_logs l1
            where 
                l1.item_id = l.item_id
                and l1.action_type = l.action_type
        )
    inner join users u 
        on  l.user_id = u.id
where 
    a.assigned_type like 'App\\\\Models\\\\User'
    and a.expected_checkin is not null
    and a.expected_checkin < '2019-11-31 12:12:12'
```

This should work on all versions of MySQL (unlike window functions, that require 8.0). Also, with an index on `action_logs(item_id, action_type, updated_at)`, this should be a very efficient option.

Side notes:

- table aliases make the query shorter and more understandable; I modified your query to use table aliases everywhere
- properly formatting your query makes it much easier to read and maintain
- conditions on `join`ed tables are better placed in the `on` clause of the `join` than in the `where` clause: I modified that too

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and the tips!

This is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.